# ¿como utilizar un solo trigger en 2 o más tablas?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Mi problema es que tengo creado un trigger que cuando en la tabla PACIENTE se inserta cualquier tipo de dato, hace una copia de esto y lo almacena en otra tabla ´AUDITORIAS´, sin embargo la base de datos que administro tiene una cantidad importante de tablas, por lo cual sería de gran ayuda si alguien me pudiese informar de alguna manera de usar este mismo Trigger para 2 o más tabla (por ejemplo, ESPECIALIDAD)
En resumen, que cuando yo inserte algo en cualquiera de las 2 tablas, esta acción se almacene en AUDITORIAS

Tabla PACIENTE

```
    create table PACIENTE (

    DOCUMENTO            char(13)             not null,
    NOMBRES              char(70)             not null,
    APELLIDOS            char(70)             not null,
    DIRECCION            char(30)             not null,
    TELEFONO             char(15)             not null,
    )
```

Tabla AUDITORIAS

```
    CREATE TABLE AUDITORIA(
    CODIGO_AU INT IDENTITY(1,1)  PRIMARY KEY,
    USUARIO_AU VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    TABLA VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    ACCION VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    REGISTRO VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(50),
    FECHA_HORA DATETIME NOT NULL
    )
```

Trigger

```
    CREATE trigger [TR_Auditoriap_Inseratr]
    ON PACIENTE
    FOR INSERT
    AS 
    BEGIN
    INSERT AUDITORIA SELECT 
   'DESCONOCIDO','PACIENTE','INSERTÓ',DOCUMENTO,RTRIM(NOMBRES)+' 
   '+RTRIM(APELLIDOS), 
    'NINGUNA',GETDATE() from inserted
    END;
```

Tabla ESPECIALIDAD

```
    create table ESPECIALIDAD (
    CODIGO_ES            char(1)             not null,
    DIA_HOR              char(10)             null,
    DESCRIPCION_ES       char(30)             not null,
    )
```

Comment: Hola Kevin.  No puedes utilizar un solo trigger en varias tablas, pero te tengo una solución. Crea un StoredProcedure que reciba los 7 parametros del inserted, eso si, debes crear un trigger por cada tabla que esta a su vez llame a este SP que se encargará de la `insert`. así si necesitas realizar algún cambio en la insert o agregar una funcionabilidad adicional, solo tendrás que editar el SP y no cada trigger

Comment: No se puede utilizar un trigger en 2 tablas. Creo que más que preguntar como utilizar un trigger en 2 tablas, debieras enfocar tu pregunta en como resolver el verdadero problema que tienes. Creo que estamos acá ante un típico caso del [problema x y](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3361/21)